# Safari does not load media queries

Tags: css, safari

This is not the first time, safari is ignoring my media queries. I am using the below style in .scss/sass .

```
    #reality-check-content {
    @media screen and (max-width: 480px){
        width: 45% !important;
    }
   }
```

When i test on chrome it works and return

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 480px)
 #reality-check-content {
   width: 45%!important;
 }
```

Likewise in firefox it works . However, in safari it does not , i just dont see my media queries. This is not the first time, i tried hiding an element the other day , it works in every browser but safari. The point is it does not seem to be loading my styling.

Comment: You are not wrapping contents of `media query` in `{ }` and believe me safari checks all these cheeky things before making `css` work for you

Comment: @GuruprasadRao is my .scss above i wrapped them . What happened then ? Why does it remove them in css?

Comment: Not sure about that part as I don't have much knowledge on `SCSS` IMHO, but working with `CSS` you need to look on these stuffs and I've read the same in many posts too.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use brackets for @media queries.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
  #reality-check-nav {
    width: 45%!important;
  }
}
```

Comment: I used it in my .scss . But it does not load on css ?

Comment: Hmm... not sure. That's weird.